# Codeigniter - Setting up cron job, not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm trying to follow the cron job [setup as seen in the documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) but I keep running into an issue. In the command line it output all of the markup in the `header.php` with the following statements at the end:

```
<h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
<p>The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled</p>
```

What I'm typing into the command line:

```
php index.php tools message
```

Is there something I need to install on the server? Here are my specs from `pecl version`.

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux lucrum 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to add this as a comment so i have to post as an answer. But judging from what you posted the error message is telling you that the MongoDB PECL extension hasn't been installed on your server. Have you checked to see if it actualy is installed? If it is then you need to look into your configuration.

Comment: It's already been installed and is required to even run MongoDB with PHP. Currently installed is `mongo 1.5.8 stable`.

Comment: Thought about it some more, found another `php.ini` file missing the extension, specially for CLI purposes. Now it's loading the whole page, not reporting just a simple message.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the page or do you expect your script to pick out specific data from it?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure. Based on the tutorial as pasted, it says you should see `"Hello Word"` of which I'm not seeing in my output, just the markup for the entire login page to my app.

Comment: You would only see Hello World if your index.php uses a controller which outputs Hello World. If i was to visit your app would the login page be the first thing i see ? if so then thats what you'll see too.

Comment: Unless I miss read that contradicts the tutorial linked in the original post. The index should only route me, not require me to edit it, which you don't do with Codeigniter framework.

Comment: According to the docs you posted if you create a controler called tools.php which outputs hello world then you should be able to access it from the comandline by doing this: yoursite.com/index.php/tools/message/to where message is your function and to is the parameter of that function.

Comment: I did create the file exactly where it goes. Yes you can access it via the browser from that URL, that's how Codeigniter works, but in this instance and the purpose of the article is to talk about how to access from the command line, which is why you type `php index.php tools message`, but I'm not getting the routing the controller, just what's in the `index.php` file. I'm assuming you have never worked with Codeigniter before and are not aware of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually I have worked with CodeIgniter before and i do understand what your trying to accomplish I'm just trying to understand why its not working for you. But hey man, I'll leave it be and let someone else try and help.

Comment: My apologies to offend, just that using the URL won't work as outlined in many stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Your not offending me, I understand how frustrating it is trying to solve a problem like this, especially when it seems to work with for everyone else. One suggestion you can try is install a barebones fresh copy of codeigniter and follow their tutorial and see if you get the expected results. If you do then look at the differences between you're existing setup and the barebones one and see if there is soemthing your missing.